# how to fix png broken image issue in bolt blogger template theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a website through bolt blogger template theme which is an XML document and I have created a separate file folder called Images and put all those png images in that.
My file path is: F:\BackupTheme\BackUp1\Images

I have added these below-given HTML codes inside the theme but it still showing the broken image and I cleared all those cache memories in my chrome browser also but no luck.

My html code would be like:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="mgn-b">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img src="../../Images/wifi.png" class="img-responsive center-block img-p" alt="WiFi" title="WiFi"/>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img src="../../Images/water.png" class="img-responsive center-block img-p" alt="Drinking Water" title="Drinking Water"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img src="../../Images/air-conditioner.png" class="img-responsive center-block img-p" alt="Air Conditioner" title="Air Conditioner"/>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img src="../../Images/kitchen.png" class="img-responsive center-block img-p" alt="In House Kitchen" title="In House Kitchen"/>
                </div>              

            </div>  
</div>
```

I'm expecting png images to be displayed but the actual result is a broken image.